# Change the top color of a TabPane in css

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have failed to change the color at the top of the tabPane in JavaFx css.Details in image

[image]

I tried

```
#myTabPane .tab-header-area{
      -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

And

```
#myTabPane{
      -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

But no positive results.

Comment: Have you assigned the id `myTabPane` to the TabPane? The proper class for the tab header background is probably `tab-header-background`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane

Comment: @hotzst Yeah,I assigned the id as `myTabPane`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the background color of `tab-header-background`. For example:

```
.tab-pane>*.tab-header-area>*.tab-header-background 
{
   -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-text-box-border, white;
}
```